# What does "man" (verb) exactly mean?

Tags: meaning

> Fire suppression equipment must be **manned**.

Does it mean that operators should be provided? The meaning for "man" is somewhat ambiguous for me.

According to Cambridge dictionary, "man" (verb) means:

> To man something such as a machine or vehicle is to be present in
>   order to operate it

According to Merriam-Webster dictionary, it means:

> to supply with people (as for service)

Does it mean that personnel should be provided along with the device being provided?

Comment: You have your answers from the dictionaries. What do you not understand?manned=there must be someone to operate it, a person must be supplied to operate it. Contrast: unmanned space vehicle....

Comment: No more than you'd expect to be supplied ***with a driver*** when you buy a car. As with a car, fire suppression equipment needs someone to operate it, but that doesn't imply the supplier must or should provide the operator as well as the "hardware".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here **manned** is used as adjective and it means **operated or controlled by people**
**e.g.**

> An outpost manned by Indian troops.
>
> **Fire suppression equipment must be manned.**

means equipment must be designed in such a way that it is operated and contolled by people.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hard to tell without context, but basically it *could* mean that someone should be available to operate the equipment - that is the most likely interpretation. Even within that, it could mean that they are actively manned - someone is standing ready to operate them at all times - or just that there is someone nearby who can stop what they are doing to operate the equipment.

***Manned*** is also occasionally used, in my experience, to mean "not automatic".